# Can I restrict the number of possible intents in response to Alexa asking?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

Sometimes in my Skill, after receiving an intent, Alexa will ask back to clarify. For example: "How many do you want to add?" In this case, the answer of the user will likely match only one Intent, (or the StopIntent).

Can I use this knowledge to improve the recognition of the answer?

Comment: I agree this would be great to have, and asked for the amazon team to consider adding something like this [here](https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs/issues/38)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time, there is no way to dynamically alter the list of intents.

In your application, however, you should check to see if you received a valid intent for the current context and provide a suitable error message.  I have heard of some people looking at easily confused intents, and making a guess that a similar, contextually correct, intent was chosen.